# The LED doesn't turn on in the STM32 simulation in Proteus

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

[image: LED IS NOT GLOWING IN PROTEUS]

The code running on STM32 is:

```
  while(1){
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_12);
            HAL_Delay(1000);
          }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a school exercise/assignment. Have you tried asking the professor? I'd hope the course materials have some known working Proteus circuits that you could use as a reference. Perhaps start with a working circuit that may be configured to do something else, add the LED, change code, remove unnecessary parts, and see if it still works. As a student, you should expect some degree of support from the teachers of the course, so don't be shy about asking for help.

Comment: You should have a 470 Ohm (or so) resistor in series with the LED to limi LED current.  This won't fix your problem, but will be important when you do fix it.

Comment: why do you ask about the LED? ... why do you not ask about the messages?

Comment: What do the warning messages exactly mean?

Comment: That can't be the code running on the MCU. It won't even compile, and even if it did, you omitted important lines of code.